# How to access variable that is in inside the method of class from top level function

Tags: flutter

I am trying to access current value of map that is in class level method from outside the function.

//This is function for call back

```
fireAlaram(String message_map) {

   Assistant(message_map).speak();
 
}
```

//this is the function that is in stateful class

```
    void do_backgroundTask() {
        var ke = todoBox.keys.cast<int>().toList();
        if (ke.length > 0) {
          for (var _k in ke) {
            if (todoBox.get(_k)!.time.compareTo(DateTime.now()) >= 0) {
              m.addAll(todoBox.get(_k)!.toMap());
            }
          }
          if (m.length > 0) {
            products = m.keys.toList();
            products.sort();
        
            setState(() {
              t = products[0];
            });
           

        AndroidAlarmManager.oneShotAt(t, 1,fireAlaram(m[t])
            );
     
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to get value of map string value when key is t, it gives null error

Comment: Also attached the error

Comment: it does not give error, callback function did not trigger

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.